# sending custom ftp commands with python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp

I'm working with a propriety system that has implemented custom FTP commands. Specifically the command that I'm interested in takes 5 arguments , is it possible to use the python ftplib to send such a complex command?

```
ftp.sendcmd()
```

The function above does not appear to be capable of send this complex command.

In my example, the function looks like this:

```
SITE_CUSTOM_CMD(args1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

I'm new to python so your feedback is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send your own command use [`FTP.sendcmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.sendcmd). This function takes a single argument which is the whole command string. Arguments are separated by spaces in FTP commands, i.e.

```
ftp.sendcmd(" ".join([cmd, args1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5]))
```